# Trademark Symbol changed to ? on SpringBoot: Debian

Tags: spring-boot, unix, tomcat, kubernetes, character-encoding

I have services developed using Spring Boot 2.2.4 which takes POST parameters as input. The problem is that if I input a string having any special symbols i.e. Copyright symbol or Trademark symbol it works fine with Windows system but when deployed on k8s, it changes to '?' symbol. I tried setting the @Consumes with charset UTF-8, setting the spring properties:

```
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled= true
spring.http.encoding.force= true
```

Still the problem persists. I am not sure if this is an encoding problem or some other configuration problem with Linux/ SpringBoot.

Comment: What exactly the ingress controller you are using right now?

Comment: I am using nginx ingress controller. Thanks